# Remove PhpMyAdmin 4.9.7 from Wampserver v.3.2.6

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I downloaded latest version of Wampserver v.3.2.6 and it has phpMyAdmin v.4.9.7 by default with phpMyAdmin v.5.1.1. It seems like it uses phpMyAdmin v.4.9.7 as default. I want to remove phpMyAdmin v.4.9.7 completely and just use phpMyAdmin v.5.1.1.

I'm using Laravel and when I run php artisan migrate it gives me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
```

I know how to fix this in Laravel, please don't tell me how to fix in Laravel.

The oldest version of Wampserver v.3.2.3 had no problem, because it had no phpMyAdmin v.4.9.7.

I think it is because of phpMyAdmin v.4.9.7. If you know any solution please help.

Comment: I am seeking the same answer. I've been searching to remove this annoying warning.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging I found the issue. There were 2 Wamp Server folders on my system. One in each drive. Apparently I used the exe files to install from [wampserver](https://www.wampserver.com/en/) and it installed in my C: (Windows). I didn't notice it. It didn't allow me to overwrite the one I really wanted to update. It came with both `PhpMyAdmin 4.9.7 & 5.1.1`.

If you want to

> remove phpMyAdmin v.4.9.7 completely

you will have to find the Wamp Server folder with phpMyAdmin v.4.9.7. Before you remove it, make sure to your alias folder has the version information in it that you want to keep: `phpmyadmin.conf` and dump the one you want to remove. Mine was `phpmyadmin4.9.7`. After removing it, `right-click` the Wamp Server icon & `Restart from zero`. You will then `PhpMyAdmin 5.1.1` (in my case).

Comment: I found out the problem, it was because of innodb-default-row-format=compact, I changed it to innodb-default-row-format=dynamic and it works fine.